# Web Map loading feature layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have requirement where i have to use web map . I have have lots of feature layers which will loaded conditionally hence in my json i have provided visibility as false for all layers then i have modify json conditionally and set visibility to true for some layers. The problem is once we set visibility to true , all the features will be loaded instead i want to set Definition or pass some query task where i can load features based on need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use FeatureLayer[.setDefinitionExpression()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#setdefinitionexpression)

Comment: We cant use FeatureLayer.setDefinitionExpression() when creating web map if it can please share us code or link.

Comment: this method is available in the application itself after the webmap has already loaded.  you can get a reference to your featureLayer using something like [responseMap].[getLayer("id")](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#getlayer)